# How do I add an individual Google+ contact to Glass without an email address?

Tags: google-plus, google-glass, google-contacts-api

I have someone in my Google+ circles who hasn't shared their e-mail address with me.  I would like to be able to share photos with this person individually through Glass, so I want to add them as a contact on the [MyGlass webpage](http://glass.google.com/myglass).  I click "Add a contact", but their name is not recognized.  I go to https://www.google.com/contacts and find the person under Circles, then I add them to the "My Contacts" group -- this doesn't help.  Do I have to make a separate Circle just for this one person so I can see them individually on Glass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Google will only add individual contacts to MyGlass which have either a phone number or an e-mail address.

Add a dummy e-mail address like 'user@[example.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)' (or a disposable alias you control) to their profile in [My Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/#contacts).  Afterwards you'll be able add this contact from MyGlass and it will show up as an individual G+ Contact on Glass.  Photo sharing will work via G+, but remember not to "Send a Message" to this contact; Glass will try to use the dummy e-mail address.